# Why does network go down when access point reboots?

Tags: reboot, wireless-access-point

I've added an [Asus RT-AC68U](http://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTAC68U/) set up in Access Point (AP) mode on to a gigabit network. Everything works fine until I reboot the AP.

The reboot causes a 45 second disruption, when the AP initializes, to other wired devices on the network. During that 45 second disruption, pings to the gateway fail. The ASUS runs the latest ASUS firmware. I also tried ASUS-Merlin firmware.

The problem occurs only when these three things are true: 1) the cable decoder box is turned on, 2) the bedroom switch is attached, 3) the router is rebooted.

Conversely, no problem to any network devices occurs if any of the above are not true; 1) the decoder box is off or, 2) the switch is removed and the two cables are joined together by an Ethernet coupler, or 3) the router is not rebooted.

So now that I understand the elements of the problem, I have no idea of the cause. The workaround is that I removed the switch and joined the two cables together with an Ethernet coupler. I have no idea why there is an interaction between the cable decoder, the router rebooting, and the bedroom switch. I've swapped out all cables, swapped the decoder box for a different model, and tried two other brands of switches -- always resulting in the same issue. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: are your network switches running the [spanning-tree protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol)?  What kind of switches are they?

Comment: They are unmanaged, minimal, cheap and popular. Two TRENDnet TEG-S81g and two TP-Link TL-SG1005D. The router is plugged into a TEG-S81g.

Comment: Updated the question with the interaction issue and the puzzling workaround. This is the most confounding network issue I've ever had.

Comment: Try giving the cable decoder box and the AP static IPs...